# How can I pass the output of a ping command to a variable within a Batch-file?

Tags: batch-file

Specifically here, I am trying to pass the output of a ping command that is piped to a Find "Reply" to a variable. From there, I'd like to take that variable and check the IP against a list of IP's to determine which subnet that IP is on. I'm thinking I can use some iteration of FOR to then split off just the IP, which I can then use from there to check against my list.

I was hoping that I could just use the FOR with the ***ping -4 -n  1 %WHATTOPING% | Find "Reply"*** as my parameter, but I don't think that is going to work.

Please let me know if my question needs any clearing up! Thank you!

So far my code is:

```
@echo off
CLS
:start
SET /p WHATTOPING= What would you like to ping?
ping -4 -n  1 %WHATTOPING% | Find "Reply"

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('ping -4 -n  1 %WHATTOPING%') do set "var=%%A"
echo %var%


PAUSE 
CLS
goto start
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('ping -4 -n  1 %WHATTOPING% ^| Find "Reply"') do set "var=%%A"
```

should work for you, but without a(n obfuscated) sample of the data you are generating with the `ping` and the value you wish to extract from that data, it can be but a hint.

The critical point is that you need to *escape* the `|` with a caret `^` in order to tell `cmd` that the pipe is part of the single-quoted command, not of the `for` that is interpreting the result of that command.

Answer (score 1):

`Reply` is language dependent (in a German Windows, it would be `Antwort`). (Besides that, it's not reliable within the same network: you can get something like `Reply from <localhost>: destination not reachable.`)

For an "international" solution, get the address from the header line (it's enclosed in `[]`):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 1 www.google.de ^|find "["') do set "IP=%%a"
echo %IP%
```